# Get kernel timeslice ID

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

Background: In my kernel driver I found a difference in time measurements that I use to trace an error. I am sure this is because in one try the driver got interrupted and had to pause until it's next time slice.
Now I'm curious if I could track this down.

My question is more like a general idea, not an actual problem:
**Is it possible to get the current time slice ID or something similar?**

This is a small pseudo code example of how I could imagine to use this code for debugging.

```
long starttime = get_time();  // Just a function to get the time
long timeslice_id = get_scheduler_timeslice();  // This is what I am looking for

do_lengthy_things();

print("Code took %d ms to run.", get_time() - starttime);

if (get_scheduler_timeslice() != timeslice_id)
  print("There was a task switch while running this code, don't wonder about the time.");
```

Comment: Can you put more details with errors?

Comment: @asktyagi Sorry no I can't :-) This is not an error situation. The difference in processing time must be caused by a task switch. Examining this I wondered if there is information if my process runs in the same time slice as some lines above of if there a task switch occurred.

Comment: If you hold a blocking lock or do I/O or anything that involves blocking, the kernel switches context to another thread. linux is a fully preemptible kernel, so kernel preemption can occur in general  --

    1. When returning to kernel-space from an interrupt handler

    2. When kernel code becomes preemptible again

    3. If a task in the kernel explicitly calls schedule()

    4. If a task in the kernel blocks (which results in a call to schedule())

Comment: @jai_s Yes these are mechanisms to switch but my thread normally stays in it's time slice. Only if it does lots ot lengthy debugging stuff I felt like it switches sometimes and tried to find a way to detect that.